# Vagrant Wazuh can't open dashboard

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I installed wazuh on Vagrant. But I can't reach my host machine.

I changed some configuration and checkup.

Firewall Disabled on Virtual Machine

default: 443 (guest) => 8001 (host) (adapter 1)

```
[vagrant@mydevbox2 ~]$ netstat -tlnp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1515            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1514            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

[vagrant@mydevbox2 ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/wazuh-manager status
wazuh-clusterd not running...
wazuh-modulesd is running...
wazuh-monitord is running...
wazuh-logcollector is running...
wazuh-remoted is running...
wazuh-syscheckd is running...
wazuh-analysisd is running...
wazuh-maild not running...
wazuh-execd is running...
wazuh-db is running...
wazuh-authd is running...
wazuh-agentlessd not running...
wazuh-integratord not running...
wazuh-dbd not running...
wazuh-csyslogd not running...
wazuh-apid is running...
```

https://ip:8001 doesn't work...

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your Vagrantfile to verify the port forwarding configuration?

For example the following Vagrantfile will automatically install Wazuh manager, indexer and dashboard and expose port 443 on 8001 on the host machine's IP:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

wazuh_ip = "192.168.43.2"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "wazuh" do |wazuh|
    wazuh.vm.box = "generic/centos7"
    wazuh.vm.provision "shell", inline: "curl -sO https://packages.wazuh.com/4.3/wazuh-install.sh && sudo bash ./wazuh-install.sh -a -i"
    wazuh.vm.network :private_network, ip: "#{wazuh_ip}"
    wazuh.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8001
    wazuh.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |pmv|
      pmv.memory = 2500
      pmv.cpus = 2
      pmv.linked_clone=true
    end
    wazuh.vm.hostname = "wazuh"
  end
end
```

In your case it seems Wazuh is working as expected and you may verify by either going to the web interface in the guest IP or by running `curl -k https://localhost`  which should provide a blank answer if the system is working correctly.